# How to honour an guid primary key with a sailsjs model in a post request

Tags: sails.js, postman

I'm want to use a new guid if no id is supplied but use the id if it supplied.
If the new guid exists I want to update rather than create a new instance.

If I send 
{ 
    "name": "First report." ,
    "id": "255af682-43c9-4d75-b0fb-7664ff51304b",
    "owner" : 9
}
via postman post request to {{url}}/report - my server running sailsjs ... the second time a new record is created.

I've tried

```
        if ( values.hasOwnProperty('id') ) {
            /* ignore */
        } else {
            values.id = uuid.v4();
        }
```

but it's not taking notice of the primary key the second time I post.

Here is the report model

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'string',
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: { type: 'string' },
        owner: {
          model: 'client'
        }
    },

    beforeCreate: function(values, callback) {
        if ( values.hasOwnProperty('id') ) {
            /* ignore */
        } else {
            values.id = uuid.v4();
        }
        callback();
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by changing the model connection to use mysql.

1. Changed the mysql connection information in config/connections.js
2. Created the mysql database with the necessary permissions.
3. Changed the connection value in config/models.js to mysql.

Sample error result.

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "PRIMARY": [
      {
        "value": "255af682-43c9-4d75-b0fb-7664ff51304b",
        "rule": "unique",
        "message": "A record with that `PRIMARY` already exists (`255af682-43c9-4d75-b0fb-7664ff51304b`)."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```